# How to fetch data from large JSON or csv fast enough, that there is no delay for the user on JS?

Tags: json, fetch

I have a link with JSON (168 MB) or CSV(60 MB), which contains data based on which I should build real-time graphs. Is there a way to get this data fast enough that there is no delay for the user?

Link - https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json

I use stream-json but its too slow (> 50s)

Comment: When you say real-time graphs, is the JSON or CSV data being constantly fed into your fetch routine? Or is the data coming in from a  GET or POST HTTP link as a huge dataset of JSON or CSV?

Comment: @horace I have a link to GitHub repo with one json file 168 Mb, and have a link with same data CSV. Than I need to have just one pies from this huge amount of data, depend of user select

Comment: Bandwidth and latency cannot be controlled with any library. The only way to affect throughput is by 1) compacting the source JSON or CSV or 2) the server selects a portion of the JSON or CSV and send back a smaller set (piece) from the source (perhaps compacted). Seems like you have the worst case scenario: you are required to fetch the entire data set and filter it *after* you receive the entire set.